# Is there a standard way to number the faces of a 6-sided die?

Tags: dice

I understand the two enantiomorphs which implement the opposite faces convention (aka the n+1 rule). I am interested in a much larger picture:

- history
- which market offers which enantiomorph?

  - casino dice
  - precision dice
  - backgammon dice
  - drugstore dice (US), shop dice (UK)
- the 15 distinct configurations
- the derivation from 6! permutations down to **the** two configurations
- why those two?
- is there a rival configuration?

Comment: What is the question? The subject line doesn't seem to match the body of your "question".

Comment: The first paragraph of my answer directly addresses the question in the subject line. Beyond that, I am hoping that those who read the remainder of my answer will be prompted to share from their knowledge additional facts related to the topics I covered.

Comment: *"Tell me all about dice"* isn't really a question though.

Comment: In light of the comments, I am rethinking my goal and how to make it conform with the standards of boardgames.stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

There is no industry-wide standard for mapping numbers 1...6 across the faces of a regular hexahedral (cubic) d6 die. Over the centuries, makers of dice have used nearly all of the possible configurations. Their choices appear in the [historical record](https://escholarship.org/content/qt3st2m41f/qt3st2m41f.pdf?t=p3dqvi), and in private collections [here](http://www.dicecollector.com/d6face.html) and
[here](http://www.aleakybos.ch/config.htm).

On the other hand, the term *standard die* is often used as a generic term to refer to a die which implements the opposite-faces convention: values on opposite faces sum to one more than the number of faces. In the case of the cubic d6, the sum is 7. [Bosch, Fathauer, and Segerman](https://www2.oberlin.edu/math/faculty/bosch/nbd.pdf) offered a thought experiment to explain how the opposite-faces convention preserves averages for imperfectly shaped dice. In a word, they explained how the convention mitigates oblateness. Since so many modern dice makers have been using this convention, it might be considered to be the de facto standard; however, this convention says nothing about how the face pairs are distributed across the die. More precisely, the term *standard d6* refers to the two-member set of cubic dice which implement the opposite-faces convention. The two configurations are mirror images. Here are their nets illustrated in the stereotypical cruciform:

```
                               Enantiomorphs
           -----------------------------------------------------
              left-handed                     right-handed
                 *****                           *****
                 * 3 *                           * 3 *
             *************                   *************
             * 2 * 1 * 5 *                   * 5 * 1 * 2 *
             *************                   *************
                 * 4 *                           * 4 *
                 *****                           *****
                 * 6 *                           * 6 *
                 *****                           *****
```

The cubic d6 has only 15 pairs of enantiomorphs. What are they? Who used them? Is there a pair with statistics which might rival the opposite-faces convention? To answer these questions, start counting configurations.

The Combinatorics

There are 6!=720 ways to map numbers 1...6 onto the faces of the cubic d6 die, but many of these configurations are rotationally equivalent. The [size of the rotational symmetry group](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/%7Ejohn/geometry/Lectures/L10.html) |G|=24. So, there are

```
                         6!/|G| = 720/24
                                = 30
```

[rotationally distinct configurations](https://www.athenopolis.net/2017/11/polyhedra.html) of the cubic d6 die. This count includes mirror images. In a perfect world, dice makers may choose any one of these 30 rotationally distinct configurations; however, the world is not perfect. The opposite-faces convention helps to mitigate some of that imperfection. How many configurations implement the opposite-faces convention?

- There are 6 ways to place "6" on an arbitrary face; this placement determines the placement of "1" on the opposite face.
- There are 4 ways to place "5" on one of the remaining faces; this placement determines the placement of "2" on the opposite face.
- Finally, there are 2 ways to place "4" on one of the remaining faces; this placement determines the placement of "3" on the opposite face.

So, there are
6!!/|G| = (6*4*2)/24
= 48/24
= 2

[rotationally distinct configurations implementing the opposite-faces convention](https://malcolmroberts.github.io/talks/dicepres.pdf)
. This count includes the two mirror images illustrated above.

The 30 configurations appear [here](http://www.aleakybos.ch/config.htm) and half of them appear [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pF8goco4ix0&t=737s) (note the correction in the Description and the silent correction in the video shortly after 10:00). Parker listed the 15 configurations in the same order as they appear in Table 1 in de Voogt et al. and with face "1" consistently appearing at the center of the cruciform. The following table is a similar listing but shows the configurations as paired mirror images.

```
                                    mirror image
                                    -------------

     1.          *****                  *****
                 * 5 *                  * 5 *
             *************          *************
             * 3 * 1 * 4 *          * 4 * 1 * 3 *
             *************          *************
                 * 6 *                  * 6 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 2 *                  * 2 *
                 *****                  *****


     2.          *****                  *****
                 * 4 *                  * 4 *
             *************          *************
             * 3 * 1 * 5 *          * 5 * 1 * 3 *
             *************          *************
                 * 6 *                  * 6 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 2 *                  * 2 *
                 *****                  *****


     3.          *****                  *****
                 * 4 *                  * 4 *
             *************          *************
             * 3 * 1 * 6 *          * 6 * 1 * 3 *
             *************          *************
                 * 5 *                  * 5 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 2 *                  * 2 *
                 *****                  *****


     4.          *****                  *****
                 * 5 *                  * 5 *
             *************          *************
             * 2 * 1 * 4 *          * 4 * 1 * 2 *
             *************          *************
                 * 6 *                  * 6 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 3 *                  * 3 *
                 *****                  *****


     5.          *****                  *****
                 * 4 *                  * 4 *
             *************          *************
             * 2 * 1 * 5 *          * 5 * 1 * 2 *
             *************          *************
                 * 6 *                  * 6 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 3 *                  * 3 *
                 *****                  *****


     6.          *****                  *****
                 * 4 *                  * 4 *
             *************          *************
             * 2 * 1 * 6 *          * 6 * 1 * 2 *
             *************          *************
                 * 5 *                  * 5 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 3 *                  * 3 *
                 *****                  *****


     7.          *****                  *****
                 * 5 *                  * 5 *
             *************          *************
             * 2 * 1 * 3 *          * 3 * 1 * 2 *
             *************          *************
                 * 6 *                  * 6 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 4 *                  * 4 *
                 *****                  *****


     8.          *****                  *****
                 * 3 *                  * 3 *
             *************          *************
             * 2 * 1 * 5 *          * 5 * 1 * 2 *
             *************          *************
                 * 6 *                  * 6 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 4 *                  * 4 *
                 *****                  *****


     9.          *****                  *****
                 * 3 *                  * 3 *
             *************          *************
             * 2 * 1 * 6 *          * 6 * 1 * 2 *
             *************          *************
                 * 5 *                  * 5 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 4 *                  * 4 *
                 *****                  *****


    10.          *****                  *****
                 * 4 *                  * 4 *
             *************          *************
             * 2 * 1 * 3 *          * 3 * 1 * 2 *
             *************          *************
                 * 6 *                  * 6 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 5 *                  * 5 *
                 *****                  *****


    11.          *****                  *****
                 * 3 *                  * 3 *
             *************          *************
             * 2 * 1 * 4 *          * 4 * 1 * 2 *
             *************          *************
                 * 6 *                  * 6 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 5 *                  * 5 *
                 *****                  *****


    12.          *****                  *****
                 * 3 *                  * 3 *
             *************          *************
             * 2 * 1 * 6 *          * 6 * 1 * 2 *
             *************          *************
                 * 4 *                  * 4 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 5 *                  * 5 *
                 *****                  *****



    13.          *****                  *****
                 * 4 *                  * 4 *
             *************          *************
             * 2 * 1 * 3 *          * 3 * 1 * 2 *
             *************          *************
                 * 5 *                  * 5 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 6 *                  * 6 *
                 *****                  *****



    14.          *****                  *****
                 * 3 *                  * 3 *
             *************          *************
             * 2 * 1 * 4 *          * 4 * 1 * 2 *
             *************          *************
                 * 5 *                  * 5 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 6 *                  * 6 *
                 *****                  *****


    15.          *****                  *****
                 * 3 *                  * 3 *
             *************          *************
             * 2 * 1 * 5 *          * 5 * 1 * 2 *
             *************          *************
                 * 4 *                  * 4 *
                 *****                  *****
                 * 6 *                  * 6 *
                 *****                  *****
```

(Readers are invited to compare their d6s against the 15 pairs above.)

Parker asked (Question #6, 11:34), "How good are our original, normal, garden-variety, six-sided dice when it comes to the values around any one verticee(sic)?" He analyzed the 15 configurations with a proof by exhaustion and provided his results as a table of statistics in the Description. He concluded that while Configuration #15 implements the opposite-faces convention (all three pairs of opposite faces sum to 7), it is the worst in terms of numerically balanced vertices. Configuration #1 is the best in terms of numerically balanced vertices but the worst in terms of the convention; Configuration #1 has only a single pair of opposite faces summing to 7. (The configuration circled in gold in the video is the left-handed version of Configuration #15. The configuration circled in purple is Configuration #1.)

In the end there are two competing configurations. Configuration #1 mitigates air bubbles; configuration #15 mitigates oblateness. The mass market chose #15. Some manufacturers chose the right-handed version of Configuration #15; others chose the left-handed version.

But wait! There's more! The cubic d6 is not the only marketed d6:

- triangular bipyramid

  - Pyramid d6, The Dice Lab
- symmetric trigonal trapezohedron

  - Slant Dice, The Dice Lab
  - Hedron D6, Tiny Tokens
  - Isodie 10, Geometrix
- asymmetric trigonal trapezohedron

  - Skew Dice, The Dice Lab
- modified triangular prism (dreidel)

  - Top d6, Wombat
- modified triangular antiprism

  - "Crystal" d6, The Dice Lab
  - Barrel Dice RPG Set, Diceforge
- (any others?)

The reader is invited to discover the configurations applied to these alternate d6s.

Comment: For completeness, there's also the modified hexagonal prism D6